# Python Sorting: Grouping Items with Same Pickup Address Across Different Brands

Tags: python, list, sorting, data-structures

I have a list of items containing brand and pickup address information. My goal is to sort the items by brand and arrange them in such a way that items with the same pickup address in different brands appear consecutively. The order within each brand's group should remain unchanged. In other words, I need to ensure that identical pickup addresses are grouped together while maintaining the original order within each brand.

This list is sort by brand.

```
items = [
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 1},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 2}, // need to move to end of Adidas
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 2}, // need to move to end of Adidas
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 3},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 3},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 4},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 5},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 5},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 5},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 5},
    {"brand": "Nike", "pick_up_address": 2},
    {"brand": "Nike", "pick_up_address": 2}
]
```

This is what I excepted to get.

```
sorted_items = [
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 1},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 3},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 3},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 4},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 5},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 5},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 5},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 5},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 2},
    {"brand": "Adidas", "pick_up_address": 2},
    {"brand": "Nike", "pick_up_address": 2},
    {"brand": "Nike", "pick_up_address": 2}
]
```

I need assistance in devising an appropriate sorting strategy or custom sorting function to achieve the desired output. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what if `"brand": "Nike"` has `"pick_up_address": 3`? If you then arrange `Adidas: ...2, 3` (at the end) with `Nike: 2, 3`  it would not still look consecutive.

Comment: I did not mention that we are guaranteed is there only one same address on two different brands

Comment: Again, let's say `"brand": "Nike"` has `"pick_up_address": 3 and 4` and there's a 3rd brand `Joma` that has `"pick_up_address": 2`. How can you then pull together the address `2` throughout those 3 brands while retaining the order?

Comment: To put it extremely, for example, if Adidas and Nike both had exactly the same number of items with exactly the same addresses, then sorting by your description would not change the order of the items from their original order. Is this the result you expected?